# Replacing "Environmental Variables" in a String which values are stored inside a JSON object. (JAVA)

Tags: java, json, string, replace, matcher

Lets say a have a String like this:

```
String str = "Lorem Ipsum Neque porro <userEnv.value1> quisquam est qui <userEnv.value2> dolorem
              ipsum quia <userEnv.value2> dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..";
```

And I have a JSON like this:

```
"userEnv":{
     "value1":"important info",
     "value2":"other important info",
     "value3":"even other important info"
}
```

I need to find a clever way to replace every value in the string that is stored in the JSON userEnv.

I think about doing something like the following:

```
        JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObject();
        jsonObject.put(
            "userEnv",
            "\"value1\":\"important info\",\"value2\":\"other important info\",\"value3\":\"even other important info\");
        
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*[<](.*)[>].*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        int groupPointer = 0;
        while (matcher.find()){

            if (jsonObject.get(matcher.group(groupPointer))!=null){
                str = str.replaceAll(
                           ".*<"+matcher.group(groupPointer)+">.*",
                           jsonObject.get(matcher.group(groupPointer))
                 );
            }
        }
```

But this is not working, did not find any group, maybe my regex is badly expressed.

Also, I am not sure about the JSON object creation.

Maybe I should post this tomorrow and not tonight over exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //using JSONObject from org.json library you could do the following
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"userEnv\":{\n" +
            "     \"value1\":\"important info\",\n" +
            "     \"value2\":\"other important info\",\n" +
            "     \"value3\":\"even other important info\"\n" +
            "}}");
    String str = "Lorem Ipsum Neque porro <userEnv.value1> quisquam est qui <userEnv.value2> dolorem " +
            "ipsum quia <userEnv.value2> dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..";
    for (String outerKey : jsonObject.keySet()) {
        JSONObject outerKeyValue = jsonObject.getJSONObject(outerKey);
        for (String innerKey : outerKeyValue.keySet()) {
            String innerKeyValue = outerKeyValue.getString(innerKey);
            str = str.replace("<" + outerKey + "." + innerKey + ">", innerKeyValue);
        }
    }
    //here str has replaced all placeHolders of type <outerKey.innerKey> for which there were values in the json
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer I realized that I need to flatten beforehand. I used another method because the Json tree was deeper (or taller) than 2 keys. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what [StringSubstitutor of Apache Commons Text](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-text) is for:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject json = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, JsonObject.class);
Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(json.getAsJsonObject("userEnv"), new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType());

Map<String, String> placeHolderToValue = map.entrySet().stream() // adding "userEnv."
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> "userEnv." + key.getKey(), Map.Entry::getValue));

StringSubstitutor sub = new StringSubstitutor(placeHolderToValue, "<", ">");
String result = sub.replace(str);

System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
Lorem Ipsum Neque porro important info quisquam est qui other important info dolorem
              ipsum quia other important info dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used the StringSubstitutor and worked really great.

I also did specify in my question that the Json Tree is a little more complex, so I needed to Flatten all keys before.

Comment: If you found an answer helpful, you may upvote it :)